# Массив ссылок на рисунки

Tags: android, java

На активити Имеется элемент  `ListView`. Для него создал свой адаптер который состоит с TextViev и ImageViev.В нужные папки закинул картинки. Картинки в адаптер передаются через массив `int[] img` массив адресов который ссылается на ресурс fizic_img. Все работоет.

```
<integer-array name="fizic_img">
    <item>0x7f020001</item>
    <item>0x7f020002</item>
    <item>0x7f020003</item>
    <item>0x7f020004</item>
    <item>0x7f020005</item>
    <item>0x7f020006</item>
    <item>0x7f020007</item>
    <item>0x7f020008</item>
    <item>0x7f020009</item>
    <item>0x7f02000a</item>
</integer-array>
```

Как поменять такой ресурс на ресурс ниже!!!

```
<array name="cat_icons">
    <item>@drawable/cat_0</item>
    <item>@drawable/cat_1</item>
    …
</array>
```

Comment: *[offtop]*

Ох. Простите, но это, на мой взгляд, просто ужасно. Посему могу дать вам лишь несколько советов:

 1. Купите и старательно прочитайте учебник русского языка. Подобная безграмотность убивает всяческое желание вчитываться в ваш вопрос и, как следствие, отвечать на него.
 2. Начните, наконец, читать документацию. Это не так страшно, как вам кажется.
 3. Научитесь формулировать свои мысли и вопросы таким образом, чтобы это было понятно не только вам.
*[/offtop]*

Comment: @falstaf, хотя некоторые вещи звучат не так уж плохо - "Имею ListView."

Comment: Не хочешь 
не отвечай!!!
От такого точно ответа не хочу!!!

Comment: @tank2007, попробуйте всё же переформулировать вопрос, если хотите получить ответ.

Comment: Вот так бы и сразу!!!
Я выполнил то, что ты просил!

Comment: Вам принципиально держать этот массив в ресурсах? Может такой вариант будет приемлемей 
int[] array = new int[]{R.drawable.cat_0, R.drawable.cat_1};

Comment: Я рассматривал такой вариант, такой вариант это моя первая проба.
У меня в конце концов должно быть 25 массивов по 500 элементов, я бы не хотел
держать их в основном коде!!!А вы!!!

Comment: мне кажется что автор пишет через гугл переводчик =) может лучше хранить ссылки в веб сервисе? если они будут меняться/дополняться

Comment: > У меня в конце концов должно быть 25 массивов по 500 элементов, я бы не хотел держать их в основном коде

Гм. Вам явно следует ещё раз подумать об архитектуре проекта. Например, используйте `assets`, последовательно пронумеровав файлы изображений. Тогда вы сможете получить нужный файл по его индексу. Что-то более конкретное трудно советовать, поскольку ваше умение формулировать вопросы и проблемы, которые вы пытаетесь решить, оставляет желать лучшего.

Comment: Вот что я хочу!
Как перенести массив int[] array = new int[]{R.drawable.cat_0, R.drawable.cat_1}; в ресурсу, но на выходе int[] должен быть

Answer (score 1):

Вы решаете задачу странным способом, как по мне.

Но всё же, простейший запрос в гугл (странно, что вы не смогли сделать этого сами) выдал два схожих решения: [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945678/android-storing-r-drawable-ids-in-xml-array) и [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347107/creating-integer-array-of-resource-ids). Наслаждайтесь.

Comment: Делал я запрос в гугл. Мне так не повезло как вам. За ссылки огромное спасибо!!!!

Comment: Да везение-то тут совсем ни при чём…